# SystemJS cannot find JQuery in Angular 2 app

Tags: jquery, angular, systemjs

I integrated JQuery in my Angular 2 app as follows:

```
typings install dt~jquery --save --global
```

I can see that typings.json was adjusted accordingly, however when running the app via *npm start* I receive this error message:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/jquery 404 (Not Found)

Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/jquery

Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/jquery
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

I do have JQuery as dependency in my index.html:

```
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

UPDATE:
I did as suggested by Igor: I deleted the entry in typings.json and added the dependency to my package.json. I removed the entire content of node_modules and ran `npm install` again. Still I encounter these compilation errors:

```
 node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(623,5): error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
 node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2872,5): error TS2374: Duplicate string index signature.
node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2873,5): error TS2375: Duplicate number index signature.
node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3246,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts(3224,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
```

I have no idea how/why I should have a duplicated type definition. This is how my package.json recently looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
"@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.4.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"chart.js": "^2.4.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"ng2-webstorage": "1.4.2",
"primeng": "^1.1.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
"systemjs": "0.19.41",
"zone.js": "^0.7.4",
"@types/jquery": "2.0.34"
```

Comment: Which Version of Angular2 you are using ?

Comment: latest one: 2.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using TypeScript version 2 or later

- Remove the jquery reference from your typings configuration file. It is now preferred to use npm to pull in type definitions.
- Update your package.json file and add `"@types/jquery": "X.X.X",` where the `x.x.x` is the version you are using. The latest is 2.0.34 ([npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery)).
- Remove any `import` references to jquery in your typescript your code.
- Just reference jquery as if it were already loaded. TypeScript should pick up the definition of `JQuery` automatically, no need to do anything else.

---

Note that TypeScript will pick up definition files even though there might not be a project reference to the definition file. As long as the definition file exists on disk anywhere in the project folder it will be picked up. This also means if there are older definition files that still exist  from previous use of `typings` they should be deleted or you will get compilation errors when TypeScript transpiles.

Comment: I did so, then I end up with compilation errors like: `node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(623,5): error TS2374: Duplicate string ind
ex signature.
node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2872,5): error TS2374: Duplicate string in
dex signature.
node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2873,5): error TS2375: Duplicate number in
dex signature.
node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(3246,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifie
r 'export='.
typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts(3224,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'e
xport='. `

Comment: npm also told me that latest version of @types/jquery is 2.0.34. This is in my package.json: "@types/jquery": "2.0.34"

Comment: @Emdee - (regarding the version) I had just updated my answer to reflect that as well.

Comment: @Emdee - about the duplicates. This is because you have multiple jquery type definitions found in the root of your project file, the other one is probably a remnant of the `typings` install you had. Delete all the other copies of the jquery typings definition file.

Comment: See my update in the initial post, I am still running into the compilation problems.

Comment: @Emdee - did you delete the content of the `typings` folder in the root of your project as well as remove the jquery reference from your `typings.json` (or maybe its `typings.config`) file?

Comment: deleting the content of the `typings` folder was the point! Thanks